# Why this is not playing songs in voice channel?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

Using the following code, my bot just connects to voicechannel and leaves saying that no video result found.

Can someone help me, please?

```
const ytdl = require('ytdl-core');
const ytsearch = require('yt-search');
module.exports = {
  name: 'play',
  description: 'to play the song.',
  async execute(message, args) {
    const voiceChannel = message.member.voice.channel;

    if (!voiceChannel)
      return message.reply('You need to be in the <#840506655685738496> channel to execute this command.');

    if (!args.length)
      return message.channel.send('You need to send second argument !');

    const connection = await voiceChannel.join();
    const videoFinder = async (query) => {
      const videoResult = await ytsearch(query);
      return (videoResult.videos.lenght > 1) ? videoResult.videos[0] : null;
    };
    const video = await videoFinder(args.join(' '));
    if (video) {
      const stream = ytdl(video.url, { filter: 'audioonly' });
      connection.play(stream, { seek: 0, volume: 1 }).on('finish', () => {
        voiceChannel.leave();
      });
      await message.reply('~~***Now playing***~~ :- ***${video.title}***');
    } else {
      message.channel.send('No video results found.');
      voiceChannel.leave();
    }
  },
};
```

Comment: Can you edit the post to include all code

Comment: Is `videoResult.videos.lenght` a typo? I've just added the code you posted to the original question. Next time, you can [edit the post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67546864/edit) yourself.

Comment: Okay, I think it's just a typo. Try to replace `videoResult.videos.lenght > 1` with `videoResult.videos.length >= 1`.

Comment: Still, not working.

Comment: Have you tried to check what the value of `video` is?

Comment: yes it's
const video = await videoFinder(args.join('  '));

Comment: Noo, I meant its value using `console.log(video)` for example.

Comment: It's showing null.

Comment: Well, if `video` is `null`, your `if (video)` will be false and you call `voiceChannel.leave()` in the else block so it leaves the channel. Maybe check the value of `videoResult` inside `videoFinder`.

Comment: It shows all the ytsearch results that I enter from discord.